# Problem when going online (php codes)

Tags: php, pdo, wamp

I have big issues with my php scripts since I went online. Some requests are executed, other are not... But when I was testing it with Wamp everything was doing fine.

Let me show you an example:

```
$answer = $db -> query("SELECT ID FROM users WHERE ID='{$_SESSION['id']}';");

$data = $answer->fetch();

if ($data['ID']=="") 

{

$req= $db->prepare('INSERT INTO users(ID, etat) VALUES(:ID, :state)');

$req->execute(array(
                    'ID'=>session_id(),
                    'state' => 'NORMAL',
                    ));
}

else

{

$db->exec("UPDATE users SET state='NORMAL' WHERE ID='{$_SESSION['id']}';");

}
```

Here the condition is ignored and only the Insert To is executed. When I reload my page, the insert to is executed again instead of the else.

Do you have any idea?

I thought that maybe it would have been a problem of php.ini configuration. But the only php.ini that I have to replace it is the Wamp one and I don't know how to adapt it...

Comment: It generally helps a lot when you do your variable/column naming in English (because there are more people here who understand English than French). I can't help you with your problem, but if I got your intent right, you could use a `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` to simplify your code to a single query.

Comment: You're right svens, I have translated now but I hope that I have not done any other mistake while translating. I'm going to have a look at the use of "on duplicate".

Comment: Are you sure of what is inside $_SESSION['id'], maybe the error occurs before your test and the SQl in not false, just your session data that is never set (or the session is lost between requests, check you do not have a new cookie each time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've found the problem on that one. In fact when I duplicated my SQL database I had forgotten to setup the Primary key like on the Wamp one... I don't know exactly why, but it works fine now...

I am going to investigate on the other problems before coming back to you!

Many thanks to all of you for your time!

Comment: In this case, you should delete your question, or at least accept your own answer so that others can tell your problem has been solved.

Comment: I must wait 2 days to accept it and I don't want to delete it. Thanks Matt

Answer (score 0):

`$_SESSION['id']` is a session variable named 'id'. `session_id()` returns session id. And they are not the same. `SELECT ID FROM users WHERE ID='{$_SESSION['id']}';` does not return the same value as `SELECT ID FROM users WHERE ID='{session_id()}';` You need either to insert `$_SESSION['id']` or select record with id ==`session_id()`.

Comment: Thanks Alex, but why does it work before going online? And at the top of my page I have written: $_SESSION['id']=session_id() so it should alter 'id'?

Comment: If you have that line (`$_SESSION['id']=session_id() `) you should be ok. I just noticed a difference between select and insert. Make sure that the record actually gets inserted and you don't restart the session after each load.